# Ошибка в функции SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начинающий программист пишу код, пишу 2 функции. Посмотрите и скажите пожалуйста альтернативы мною писаной функции и в чем ошибка. Не судите строго.
Код

```
def user_spisok(name, age):
 for names in name:
        print("\nHello,"+ name.title())
print("\ How are old you ? ")
for ages in age :
 print(ages)
spisok ['eva', age = 13]
```

Код ошибки.

```
user_spisok(spisok)
 File "user.py", line 7
    spisok ['eva', age = 13]
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код и ошибку нормально

Comment: Если в последней строке у вас предполагается вызов функции, то нужно писать именно имя функции user_spisok, и передавать параметры в круглых скобках: `user_spisok('eva', age=13)`

Comment: @Валентина Турчин  установите PyCharm,он будет подсвечивать ошибки опечатки и подсказывать в некоторых местах. например круглые скобки, а не квадратные и тд.очень полезная штука.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что ты передаешь функции - одну переменную (список, в котором список из имен и возрастов).

В твоем случае, надо передавать 2 переменные ( или же списка, если
смотреть весь код)

```
def user_spisok(name=None, age=0):
      for names in name:
        print("\nHello,",names)
        print(" How are old you ? ")
      for ages in age :
        print(ages)
    
spisok=['Chris', "jesse"]
age=[10,5]
user_spisok(spisok, age)
```

А вообще, правильно будет сделать так -

```
def user_spisok(name=None, age=0):
  for names in name:
    print("\nHello,",names)
    print(" How are old you ? ")
    x=name.index(names) # Здесь получаем индекс имени в списке name 
    print (f"Age is {age[x]}") # Здесь показываем возраст, который имеет тот же индекс

spisok=['Chris', "jesse"]
age=[10,5]
user_spisok(spisok, age)
```